# Material-UI TextField is not updating value when using setValue of react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to set new value that I'm getting from props and than update the TextField component with setValue of react-hook-form library.

The problem is that the value sometimes staying empty and sometimes the label is not floating (shrinking).

Codesandbox **(Please notice that I built wrapper component for TextField over there)**
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-bird-tq4sf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

```
  setValue("business_name", "netanel" || someData);
```

This code overwrites the value. This codes writes `netanel` to the field, if it is true, which is always the case. [Connected issue](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/220#issuecomment-649523265).

Do it like this:

```
  setValue("business_name", someData);
```

So someData is always defined anyway.

Since you are already defining the fallback value in the destruction here: `{ someData = "netanel" }`

**Update**:

To prevent the label bug, you need to define a default value, so that the initial value passed is not null or undefined.

So change your textfield to this:

```
 <Controller
    as={MuiTextField}
    name={name}
    control={control}
    label={label}
    defaultValue=""
  />
```

and it works.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the codesandbox. please see the case now:
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-bird-tq4sf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok what are you trying to do? You are downloading a website? And you removed the default value for some data.

Comment: No. this is some dummy api that I put there.
In my original project I fetch some regular string value and trying to insert him to the TextField.
The problem is the floating label is not shrinking and floating when the value is arriving.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue with Formik.  I had the initialValue set to null.  Changing the default to "" fixed the issue of the form label not shrinking (`data-shrink` set to true)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the label isn't floating or shrinked, then the value you are trying to insert into the field is just gonna be an empty string then I guess? Also, think about completely removing the dependency array from the useEffect like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Code here
})
```

instead of this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Code here
}, [.....]) <-- REMOVE THAT ARRAY
```

Maybe give that a try - in combination with the previous answer?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/8544

You need the TextField to be wrapped with Controller

Example (You can use TextField instead of Select): https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-curie-stss8q?file=/src/App.js